# ajax webapi call returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am following some online ajax tutorials, the example is about calling a webapi using GET method, here is the script section on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ulEmployees = $('#ulEmployees');
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "http://localhost:35468/api/employee",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    ulEmployees.empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        var fullName = value.FirstName + ' ' + value.LastName;
                        ulEmployees.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $('#btnClear').click(function () {
            ulEmployees.empty();
        });
    });
</script>
```

It should render the emoloyee first and last name within a list item in the .

```
<div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Get All Employees" />
    <input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear" />
    <ul id="ulEmployees">

    </ul>
</div>
```

the each function iterates the on the object but it displays undefined in the html

does anyone know a solution to this ?

Comment: What is the value of `data`?  What is actually being returned from the server?

Comment: That means either the `value.FirstName` or the `value.LastName` is undefined is undefined in the response.  To get better details, stick a debugger inside the loop and see what you are getting.

Comment: If data is having JSON String, then you need to parse it to JSON object first using JSON.parse() function.

Comment: value is the second object that receives the data in the each function, I am trying to populate the properties firstName and lastName of the value object that is being passed to the function, it loops ok but just renders undefined.

Comment: @Nishesh I am playing up with the parse method a bit and will see if that solves the problem, fiddler shows that the json object is returned ok and the number of the undefined <li> rendered on the page matches the number of rows in my sql table.

Comment: Try add `console.log()` into `$.each(data, function (index, value) {
console.log(value);
var fullName = value.FirstName + ' ' + value.LastName;
ulEmployees.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>');
});` and take a look what kind of data contains `value`, maybe it isn't object, but another array, or fields names in data don't match those in function.

Comment: i tried console.log but it faile for some reason
I also tried parsing data object received by each function and it didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

the problem was because the field names FirstName and LastName was incorrect, 
correct field names are firstName and lastName thats why the object was not populating them in a correct manner.